# Criteria/Standard for Factory Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

What are the criteria's for a factory pattern i.e 
a) to say that the code follows the factory pattern?
b) align with the factory pattern standard?

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged with the homework tag. This is a rather vague question, in any case.

Comment: Not a homework? I wanted to know in detail...Could you please help me? My question is if a person says he has followed the factory pattern what the checks/criterias to verify whether the code has followed the factory pattern. example, single abstract object needs to be returned.

Comment: The Factory pattern means that instead of instantiating objects directly, you call a function of a factory class, which then returns the instantiated object. Check out [Factory method pattern on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), or [this classic book on design patterns](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1342578248&sr=8-1).

Comment: Any other criteria..This is fine...

Comment: That's pretty much the only criteria.